# How can I extract a substring from a string, avoiding including the delimiters?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having some trouble to extract a substring without including the delimiters.

```
x =  "- dubuque3528 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:"
```

or

```
x = "- - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:"

user_name = re.findall('.-.*\[', x)
```

That returns: `"- dubuque3528 ["`
or `"- - [".` 
I would like to retrieve `"dubuque3528"` or `"-"` instead.

Comment: Use `-\s*(.*?)\s*\[`

Comment: It seems like you want `x.split()[1]` - is regex really needed here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
-\s*(.*?)\s*\[
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p4mrki/1). *Details*:

- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Wtb2KC):

```py
import re
x = ["- dubuque3528 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:", "- - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:"]
for s in x:
    m = re.search(r'-\s*(.*?)\s*\[', s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
-\s+(\S+)\s+\[
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/hzUZQo/1) for above regex.

You can run this above regex in Python like as follows, written and tested in Python3:

```
import re
x = ["- dubuque3528 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:", "- - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:"]
for val in x:
  m = re.search(r'-\s+(\S+)\s+\[', val)
  if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output will be as follows:

```
dubuque3528
-
```

***Explanation of above regex:***

```
-\s+   ##Matching hash followed by 1 or more occurrnces of spaces.
(\S+)  ##Creating 1st capturing group where matching 1 or more non-spaces here.
\s+\[  ##Matching 1 or more occurrences of spaces followed by [.
```